# Beginning Html/CSS Two Column Web Design (issues with padding and borders)

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I am just starting a design using HTML and CSS to do a two column page with no header, just left column and right column that will cover the full page top to bottom. The left column will be 133 px wide and the issue I am having is that there is constantly a standard margin pushing the column left and down from the left hand corner of the page. I have tried setting every setting with margin and padding to 0 but nothing seems to be removing the margin from the page.

The html code I have so far is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content"" />
<meta name="author" content="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="body">
<div id="sidebar">
<img src="header.jpg">
</div>

<div id="main">
Hello
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The css style sheet is:

```
#body {
margin: 100;
}

#sidebar {
width: 133px;
float: left;
margin: 100;
overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
margin-left: 135px;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things : if CSS property value is not `0` you should use units (i.e. `100px`,`100%`, `10rem`, `1em`  and so on). Also only `body` element in your example has default `margin`, and you are trying to manipulate `#body`'s (`div` with `id = "body"`) `margin` :

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Anyway, the text above points out your mistakes, but doesn't suggest you any solutions. There are three possible ways to achieve what you want, a long way short :

- `absolute` positioning ( with `top : 0` and `bottom : 0` to content);
- `table` layout .
- `flex` layout .

My favorite solution is to use `table` layout to I am posting it below.

***HTML :***

```
<body>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="sidebar"><img src="header.jpg"/></div>
        <div id="main">Hello</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

***CSS :***

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height:100%; }
#body { display:table; table-layout:fixed; height:100%; width:100%; }
#sidebar { width: 133px; height:auto; background:red; display:table-cell; }
#main { background:blue; display:table-cell; }
```

***Example :***

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3na7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a margin on the actual `body` tag.

You can remove this with:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also, if you wanted your `div` that has the `#body` id attribute to have a "100" margin, you need to specify a unit:

```
#body {
    margin: 100px;
}
```

PS. To avoid confusion, don't name classes or IDs after actual HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 97%; }
#sidebar {margin: 0px; width: 133px; float: left;}
#main {margin-left: 133px; float: left; }
```

Maybe the body tag needs clearer specifications.

P.S. Yeah, it seems like you didn't specify the margin and the padding for the  tag.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help.

This line in particular seemed to have fixed the problem

body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height:100%; }

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you for the help.

This line in particular seemed to have fixed the problem

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height:100%; }
```